# Cosmology: equation of motion for a scalar field in conformal time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, time, field-theory

So, I've derived the equation of motion for a scalar field in "normal" time, $t$:

$$
\ddot{\phi}+3H\dot{\phi}+\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}
$$

Then, using the expressions for the scalar field density, $\rho_{\phi}$, and pressure, $P_{\phi}$, but transformed into conformal time:

$$
\rho_{\phi}=\frac{1}{2a^{2}}\left(\frac{d\varphi}{d\eta}\right)^{2}+V(\varphi)
$$

$$
P_{\phi}=\frac{1}{2a^{2}}\left(\frac{d\varphi}{d\eta}\right)^{2}-V(\varphi)
$$

Differentiating $\rho_{\phi}$ above and then substituting that, with the expressions for $\rho_{\phi}$ and $\rho_{\phi}$ back into the continuity gives me:

$$
\frac{d^{2}\phi}{d\eta^{2}}+3aH\frac{d\phi}{d\eta}+a^{2}\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}=0
$$

But it should be:

$$
\frac{d^{2}\phi}{d\eta^{2}}+2aH\frac{d\phi}{d\eta}+a^{2}\frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}=0
$$
The 3 is actually a 2? Can anyone work through the trick or transformation which gives this?

(Please note, some may use the notation $\tau$ for conformal time, or that the derivative with respect to conformal time is $\phi^{\prime}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The continuity equation is
$$
\dot{\rho} = -3H(t)(\rho + p),
$$
or, in conformal time,
$$
\tag 1 \rho{'} = -3aH(\eta) (\rho + p)
$$
By using the espression for $\rho$, we have that
$$
\tag 2 \rho{'} = -\frac{a'}{a^{3}}(\varphi {'})^{2} + \frac{1}{a^{2}}\varphi{'}\varphi{''} + \frac{dV}{d\varphi}\varphi{'} = -\frac{H}{a}(\varphi {'})^{2} + \frac{1}{a^{2}}\varphi{'}\varphi{''} + \frac{dV}{d\varphi}\varphi{'},
$$
and substituting $(2)$ and expressions for $\rho , p$ into $(1)$ we have
$$
-\frac{H}{a}(\varphi {'})^{2} + \frac{1}{a^{2}}\varphi{'}\varphi{''} + \frac{dV}{d\varphi}\varphi{'} = -\frac{3H}{a}(\varphi {'})^{2} \Rightarrow
$$
$$
\varphi {''} + 2Ha\varphi {'} +a^{2}\frac{dV}{d\varphi}\varphi{'} = 0
$$

Comment: Perfect. Makes sense now as I see I should have perhaps used $a(\eta)$ instead of a in my notation, I would have seen it would be neccessary to use the chain rule for that! Many thanks.